# How to replace a JSON value in Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

How do I replace a value in a JSON value in Play?
Code to illustrate:

```
def newReport() = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    var json = request.body
    if((json \ "customerId").as[Int] == -1){
      // replace customerId after some logic to find the new value
    }
    json.validate[Report](Reports.readsWithoutUser).map {
      case _: Report =>
```

Comment: you don't manipulate json strings. down that road lies madness. you convert the json string to a native data structure, manipulate the structure, then re-encode to json.

Comment: Like MarcB, or use Json Coast2Coast features http://mandubian.com/2012/10/29/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part3-json-transformers/

Comment: If [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18069519/2643828) was helpful for you, please select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 37):

According to the [Play Documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0.x/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsObject.html), JsObjects have a method `++` that will merge two JsObjects. So, when you have your new integer value, you simply need:

```
val updatedJson = json.as[JsObject] ++ Json.obj("customerId" -> newValue)
```

As of Play 2.4.x you can use `+`:

```
val updatedJson = json.as[JsObject] + ("customerId" -> newValue)
```

(NOTE: the `+` method was added already in 2.1.x but adds a duplicate field to the object instead of replacing the existing value in versions prior to 2.4.x)

Comment: [Json Transformers (coast to coast)](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonTransformers#JSON-coast-to-coast-design) are currently the standard

Answer (score 4):

One approach is, as Marc B says, convert the JSON to something like a case class, manipulate that, and then create a new JSON.

However you can also use JSON 'transformers'. Effectively what you do is build a Reads[SomeThing] object. This object is passed to the transform method which you call on your JSON object. It will change the JSON object and return a Success(result) or Failure(error) where result is the new modified JSON. Here's a (comparatively)*very* simple example:

using json of format: {key -> value}

```
def jsonXForm(value: String) = (__ \ "customerId").json.update(
  (__ \ "customerId").json.put(JsString(value))
)
json.transform(jsonXForm(yourNewValue)) match {...}`
```

There is a *decent* guide [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers)

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```
val updatedJson = if((request.body \ "customerId").as[Int] == -1){
  val newId = JsObject(Seq(("customerId",JsString("ID12345"))))
  (request.body ++ newId).as[JsValue]
} else request.body

updatedJson.validate[Report](Reports.readsWithoutUser).map {
  case _: Report =>
```

Comment: You can't update the value in place since the Play Json data structures are immutable, but you can create a new JsValue that is identical except for the updated field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering moving away from all of those immutable "JSON" solutions. It's just making the code a horrible mess. This is how it would look in [SON of JSON](http://github.com/wspringer/sonofjson):

```
import nl.typeset.sonofjson._

val json = …
if (json.customerId.as[Int] == -1) {
  json.customerId = 987938
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a glorified version of Zeimyth's answer that uses implicit conversion

```
implicit class JsObjectEnhancer(jsObject: JsObject) {
  def update(args: (String, Json.JsValueWrapper)*): JsObject = {
    jsObject ++ Json.obj(args: _*)
  }
}
```

**usage** (json must be of type JsObject and the implicit class should be in scope)

```
json.update("customerId", 1000)
```