# How to change value in nested Json

Tags: json, playframework

This is similar to [How to replace a JSON value in Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649141/how-to-replace-a-json-value-in-play), but in a more complex situation.

Consider a previosly constructed value.

```
val x = Json.obj(
     "key_a" -> "value_a",
     "key_b" -> Json.obj(
          "key_a" -> 0,
          "key_b" -> 1,
          "key_c" -> Json.obj(
              "key_a" -> Json.obj(
                  "key_a" -> "value_a",
                  "key_b" -> 2
              ),
              "key_b" -> "value_b",
              "key_c" -> "value_c"
          ),
     "key_c" -> "value_c",
     ...
)
```

Suppose I wanted to change `x \ "key_b" \ "key_c" \ "key_a" \ "key_a"` to be `"new_value"`.

I think that objects are immutable in `play.api.libs.json`, so I think I'm actually looking for a *copy* of the original, with the one value changed.

What is the best way to do this?

---

I don't think this is a pathological use case.

In Javascript, it would be a one-line

```
x.key_b.key_c.key_a.key_a = 'new_value';
```

I'm hoping that a Scala solution won't be much worse.

Comment: You don't modify JSON. It's too easy to introduce a syntax error and kill the entire json construct. You decode the json back to a native data structure, make your modifications there, then re-encode back to json.

Comment: @MarcB, by "json", I meant it in the same way as in the referenced question, as a member of the `play.api.libs.json` package, not a value of type `String`.